# Android: Saving a picture taken from an App and attaching it to email

Tags: android, android-camera, email-attachments

I am trying to create an App that takes a picture when a button is pressed and then attaches it to email when a send button is pressed. The code I have shows that the picture is attached to the email, but the attachment is not sent when I check the email I sent it to.The image is not saved in the SD card too.

I call the initialize function in my onCreate() to initialize variable.Also I dont know where to put the SaveImage() function which has to save the image once it's taken. I put it in the onActivityResult() but does not work.
Thanks in advance!

```
private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Picture);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendMessage);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageReturn);
    MessageTyped = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MessageField);
    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
    camera.setOnClickListener(this);

    pngDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    // Loose convention inferred from app examples
            "My Images");

    if (!pngDir.exists())
        pngDir.mkdirs();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.Picture:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        SaveImage();//<------------------WHERE DOES THIS GO?

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

        break;

    case R.id.SendMessage:

        EditTextToString();

        EmailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        EmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "bipush.osti@gmail.com" });
        EmailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                MessageToBeReceived);

        // EmailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        EmailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        EmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(EmailIntent,
                "Choose an Email client :"));
        break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}

private void EditTextToString() {
    MessageToBeReceived = MessageTyped.getText().toString();
}

private void SaveImage() {

    File pngFile = new File(pngDir, "jetsam.jpeg");
    // Save file encoded as PNG
    pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pngFile);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation of [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)! If you didn't gave EXTRA_OUTPUT (uri with location where image should be saved), then in result you will get "small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object".

So just add uri to intent when requesting a picture and pass same uri to ACTION_SEND:

```
case R.id.Picture:
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getUriForNewFile()); // you have to implement youself getUriForNewFile()

    startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

    break;
```